# Visual C++ program crashed when accessing a virtual function returned static variable

Tags: c++, static, crash, virtual

I have a crash problem with my Visual C++ program (VC11) when it tries access a static variable which is returned by a virtual function.

in .h file: (detail skipped)

```
class BaseAggregateFunction 
{
  public:
    static const ClassHandle handle;
    virtual const ClassHandle& GetClassHandle() const { return handle; }
};
class RowAggregateFunction : public BaseAggregateFunction
{
  public:
    static const ClassHandle handle;
    virtual const ClassHandle& GetClassHandle() const { return handle; }
};
class RowSum : public RowAggregateFunction
{
  public:
    static const ClassHandle handle;
    virtual const ClassHandle& GetClassHandle() const { return handle; }
};
```

(There are a bunch of similar classes)

and in .c file the static members are initialized

```
const ClassHandle BaseAggregateFunction::handle("BaseAggregateFunction");
const ClassHandle RowAggregateFunction::handle("RowAggregateFunction", BaseAggregateFunction::handle);
const ClassHandle RowSum::handle("RowSum", RowAggregateFunction::handle);
```

And now there are cases to new a

```
BaseAggregateFunction& f = new RowSum(...);
const ClassHandle& h = f.GetClassHandle();
Logger::Instance() << LogHeader << MsgClass(MsgClass::Information)
  << "Function is a " << h.Name() << EndMsg;
```

And in the crash dump file I see h address is 0x000005, which of course is not accessible! How can a virtual class return an invalid variable? It is suppose to be static! What could be the case? How can I fix it?

BTW, this program runs same logic thousands times one day, it crashes in the middle of the day.

I added logs to trace and see f is created and deleted several times. This is normal. When problem happens, same memory address is new'd to f, but with a different type -- could that be a problem?

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: BaseAggregateFunction& f = **new** RowSum? Does it compile?

Comment: The problem is in code you haven't shown us. Please edit your post and provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and any other information relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti, Sorry I missed a * when I type.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious sorry it is impossible to post all code here, source codes accumulate 80MB, and they are private

Comment: Nobody is asking you to post the entire code. What _is_ being suggested is you take the problem code and reduce it to a manageable representation that reproduces the problem and _can_ be posted.